# How can i use Mockito to test forward only?

Tags: junit, controller, mockito, forward

The Controller use request.getParameter to forward, the code like below

```
public class ComputingController extends HttpServlet {

    public ComputingController() {
        super();
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String reDirect = request.getParameter("redirect");
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;

        if ( "update".equals( reDirect ) ) {

            UpdateData updateData = new UpdateData();
            String updateResult = updateData.doUpdateData();
            request.setAttribute( "updateResult", updateResult );

            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/computing/success.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else {

            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/computing/error.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

I use Junit and Mockito to test forward.

But when i execute the test (like below), it will both execute updateData.doUpdateData() in the controller.

How can i use the Mockito let it don't execute updateData.doUpdateData() but forward ?

```
public class ComputingControllerTest {

    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Mock
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @Mock
    RequestDispatcher rd;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void doGet_testForward() throws Exception {

        String reDirect = "update";

        when(request.getParameter("redirect")).thenReturn( reDirect );

        when(request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/computing/success.jsp")).thenReturn(rd);

        new ComputingController().doGet(request, response);

        verify(rd).forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

Comment: As is, you can't. To be able to do it, you would have to provide a mock UpdateData to the servlet, and the servlet would have to use that mock UpdateData, instead of creating its own new one every time. That's basically the principle of dependency injection.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this...

```
UpdateData updateData = new UpdateData();
String updateResult = updateData.doUpdateData();
request.setAttribute( "updateResult", updateResult );
```

You cannot really skip it completely and with only modifying your test you will not get far. So, what you need is a way to inject another UpdateData() in there (which you then can mock). A possibility would, for example, be a factory pattern...

```
private UpdateDataFactory factory;

public ComputingController(UpdateDataFactory factory) {
    super();
    this.factory = factory;
}

public ComputingController() {
    super(new DefaultUpdataDataFactory()); // simply creates a new UpdateData();
    this.factory = factory;
}
```

Now you can write instead...

```
UpdateData updateData = this.factory.createUpdataData();
```

And inside your test, you can mock the factory and insert it...

```
@Mock
private UpdateDataFactory factory;

@Mock
private UpdateData data;

...

when(factory.createUpdataData()).thenReturn (data);
new ComputingController(factory).doGet(request, response);
```

Now the call to doUpdataData() will to nothing, since it only goes to the mock, but you can verify it

Oh, and you can do the creation of the ComputingController (and injection of the mock) automatically via @InjectMocks...

```
 @InjectMocks
 private ComputingController controller;
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help. it's useful to me ~

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to achieve that without modifying existing source code of `ComputingController` class.

If you are open to modify `ComputingController` , below is what you can do to mock call - `updateData.doUpdateData()` ,

1. Create a method `getUpdateData()` in `ComputingController` with default or `protected` level accessibility ( `private` will not work and `public` is not advised ) ,

`UpdateData getUpdateData() {return new UpdateData();}`

2. Replace line `new UpdateData();` with `getUpdateData()` in `ComputingController`
3. Create a non-public class `ComputingControllerTestable` in `public class ComputingControllerTest`

`class ComputingControllerTestable extends ComputingController { 
private UpdateData updateData;
@Override protected void getUpdateData(){return updateData;} 
protected void setUpdateData(UpdateData updateData){this.updateData=updateData;}
}`

4. Now, in your test class, replace your **class-under-test** type to `ComputingControllerTestable`  instead of `ComputingController`
5. In your `ComputingControllerTest`, declare a mocked field , `@Mock private UpdateData updateData;`
6. Now in your `@Before` method of test class, call setter method of `ComputingControllerTestable` for mocked field of test class , `testObj.setUpdateData(updateData);`  where `testObj` is **class-under-test** object created in step # 4.

I have assumed that your class-under-test and test class are in same package.

Easy way ( to avoid all 6 above steps ) is to declare `UpdateData`  object as a dependency ( instance field ) in `ComputingController` class instead of creating a new `UpdateData` each time inside `doGet` method and mock that dependency in `ComputingControllerTest`

Hope it helps !!